# Skip an extra line after particular row

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have a table which has 3 columns and it has about 10 rows. But what I want to do is skip an extra line after a particular row.

Here is my code;

```
Paragraph paragraphTable3 = new Paragraph();
paragraphTable3.SpacingBefore = 20f;
paragraphTable3.SpacingAfter = 10f;

PdfPTable third_table = new PdfPTable(3);
third_table.TotalWidth = 560f;
third_table.LockedWidth = true;
third_table.SetWidths(new float[] { 2.4f,0.1f, 6.6f });

third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Responsibilities Held ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase( Responsibilities_held, other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });

third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description of Work Done", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase( Description_of_work_done, other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
```

I'm getting the output like this;

```
Responsibilities Held           : Blah bluh bluh bluh bluh ............................
                                  bluh ..........bluh ...

Description of Work Done        : Blu....................................h..............
                                  bluh.........................

Present Address                 : Blu....................................h..............
                                  bluh.........................Extra space after here

Additional Qualifications       : Blu....................................h..............
                                  bluh.........................
```

I want to add extra space after *Present Address*

Please help me....
Thank You

Comment: @DrKoch Avoid edits that change the meaning. Inserting is anything but Skipping.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what you expect, and what you're currently getting, if you want us to be anywhere near understanding your situation.

Comment: I ' m getting the out put like this;

Comment: I don't see any "line-breaking" in your code, but I do in your output, which leads me to assume that the code is incomplete (I would be sure of it, if I was familiar with those Pdf classes). But your question is almost a question, so keep it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add some extra space between two rows, why don't you add an extra (empty) row with a fixed height?

I took your code snippet that adds two rows to a table, and I added an extra cell with colspan 3 between those two rows. I defined the height of this rows as 30 user units (which corresponds with 30 points):

```
PdfPTable third_table = new PdfPTable(3);
third_table.TotalWidth = 560f;
third_table.LockedWidth = true;
third_table.SetWidths(new float[] { 2.4f,0.1f, 6.6f });

third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Responsibilities Held ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase( Responsibilities_held, other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.FixedHeight = 30.0f;
third_table.AddCell(cell);

third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description of Work Done", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase( Description_of_work_done, other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PaddingBottom as the cells property like this.

```
new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Responsibilities Held ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0, PaddingBottom = 10f }
```